# How to use a java.sql.Timestamp in JSF view with converter

Tags: java, jsf, jdbc, timestamp, converters

How can I use a model property with type of `java.sql.Timestamp` in a JSF date component like PrimeFaces `<p:calendar>`? This component needs an instance of `java.util.Date` for its input and it will also return the same type of `java.util.Date`.

Is it possible to create a converter for this case? How do I implement a converter to convert `java.sql.Timestamp` to `java.util.Date`? I think I need a JSF converter with `getAsObject()` and `getAsString()`, but I don't know where should I do the conversion?

Actually in this case I have a `List<Model>` to be displayed in `<p:dataTable>`. In each rows, I can set the startDate and endDate directly from the table. So I need to use the model property directly to get the latest / updated data from the table during `save()` process.

This is sample for my model:

```
public class Model {

    private Timestamp startDate;
    private Timestamp endDate;

    public Timestamp getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Timestamp startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Timestamp getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Timestamp endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

}
```

This is sample for my bean:

```
public class PageBean {

    private List<Model> listModel;

    public String save() {
        // Process insert / update listModel to database here
        return "next-page"
    }

    public List<Model> getListModel() {
        return listModel;
    }

    public void setListModel(List<Model> listModel) {
        this.listModel = listModel;
    }
}
```

And this is sample for my xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{pageBean.listModel}" var="model" >
    <p:column headerText="Start Date">
        <p:calendar value="#{model.startDate}" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" ></p:calendar>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="End Date">
        <p:calendar value="#{model.endDate}" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" ></p:calendar>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{pageBean.save()}" ajax="false" />
```

I think it is OK to use the model directly if the model property type is `java.util.Date`, but I got type of `java.sql.Timestamp` here.

Comment: Do you use a jpa framework? If so just declare the field of a java.util.date

Comment: Yes, but I can't change the property type to `java.util.Date` since all generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is by creating a model that is separated with persistence layer types as mentioned by @BaulusC. But I found a solution (actually a trick) that fit my case, that is by using `java.util.Map` or creating another model for binding with view, but it requires a little more work. You need to put the values from the map or the model mapper to your actual model.

1. By using a `java.util.Map`

This is the sample bean:

```
public class PageBean {

    private List<Model> listModel;
    private List<Map> listMap;

    public String save() {
        // Move the values from listMap to listModel
        listModel = new ArrayList<Model>();
        for (Map map : listMap) {
            Model model = new Model();
            model.setStartDate(new Timestamp(((Date) map.get("startDate")).getTime());
            model.setEndDate(new Timestamp(((Date) map.get("endDate")).getTime());
            listModel.add(model);
        }
        // Process listModel to database ...
        return "next-page"
    }

    public List<Map> getListMap() {
        return listMap;
    }

    public void setListMap(List<Map> listMap) {
        this.listMap = listMap;
    }
}
```

in xhtml page we use `listMap` for `<p:dataTable>` value:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{pageBean.listMap}" var="map" >
    <p:column headerText="Start Date">
        <p:calendar value="#{map.startDate}" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" ></p:calendar>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="End Date">
        <p:calendar value="#{map.endDate}" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" ></p:calendar>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{pageBean.save()}" ajax="false" />
```

2. By creating another model

The sample of new model for binding with the view:

```
public class ModelMapper {

    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

}
```

in bean:

```
public class PageBean {

    private List<Model> listModel;
    private List<ModelMapper> listModelMapper;

    public String save() {
        // Move the values from listModelMapper to listModel
        listModel = new ArrayList<Model>();
        for (ModelMapper modelMapper : listModelBinder) {
            Model model = new Model();
            model.setStartDate(new Timestamp(modelMapper.getStartdate().getTime());
            model.setEndDate(new Timestamp(modelMapper.getEndDate().getTime());
            listModel.add(model);
        }
        // Process listModel to database ...
        return "next-page"
    }

    public List<ModelMapper> getListModelMapper() {
        return listModelMapper;
    }

    public void setListModelMapper(List<ModelMapper> listModelMapper) {
        this.listModelMapper = listModelMapper;
    }
}
```

in xhtml page we use `listModelMapper` for `<p:dataTable>` value:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{pageBean.listModelMapper}" var="mapper" >
    <p:column headerText="Start Date">
        <p:calendar value="#{mapper.startDate}" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" ></p:calendar>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="End Date">
        <p:calendar value="#{mapper.endDate}" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" ></p:calendar>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{pageBean.save()}" ajax="false" />
```

This workaround needs no modification to the actual model, although we need to do other things for moving the values to the actual model. It works well for me. Hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 4):

You are in first place not supposed to have a persistence layer specific typed property in your model. Your model should have a `java.util.Date` property. Instead, your persistence layer should be altered to be able to deal with `java.util.Date` model properties.

Do the conversion in the persistence layer instead.

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(i, new Timestamp(model.getDate().getTime()));
```

The other way round is not necessary as `java.sql.Timestamp` is already a subclass of `java.util.Date`.

Comment: I edited my question, adding a sample code. I think I need to edit the `startDate` and `endDate` directly in the `<p:dataTable>`, do you get it Sir?

Comment: Was my answer hard to understand? You need to replace `Timestamp startDate` and `Timestamp endDate` by `Date startDate` and `Date endDate` in the model and do the conversion in persistence layer. The model should be **not aware** of any persistence layer specific types. Otherwise, there's means of tight coupling (which causes the model to be unshareable between the persistence layer and view layer as you currently encountered).

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but I look for other solutions. I know it will be OK if I change all the properties with type `Timestamp` to `Date` but unfortunately it is not possible for me to do that since all my models and DAO was generated. Thank you anyway.

Comment: That generator is then simply doing a bad job. You'd need to fix/reconfigure that instead of looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate timestamp to date and vise versa.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
...
private Timestamp timestamp;
...
public Timestamp getTimestamp() {
   return timestamp;
}
public void setTimestamp(Timestamp timestamp) {
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public Date getDate() {

     return timestamp == null ? null : new Date(timestamp.getTime());
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
     timestamp = date == null ? null : new Timestamp(date.getTime())
}
```

JSF:

```
<p:calendar id="button" value="#{bean.date}" showOn="button" />
```

Comment: Thank you, I got what you try to explain. But I have a list to edit in a `<p:dataTable>` directly. The list size is unpredictable, so I don't think I can use any variables as a mediator. Any suggestions?